# Remove a part of lines in a column in a file?

Tags: linux

I have a file as below.

```
1_2345_A_T 0.123 A T 0.0094
4_9784_C_G 0.00034 C G 0.924
10_536_AAAA_TGGTT 0.4456 AAAA TGGTT 0.00045
3_9874_C_T 0.55563 C T 0.8824
5_35555_A_T 0.123 A T 0.0094
....
```

There are 39000000 lines.

I want to make the file as below.

```
1_2345 0.123 A T 0.0094
4_9784 0.00034 C G 0.924
10_536 0.4456 AAAA TGGTT 0.00045
3_9874 0.55563 C T 0.8824
5_35555 0.123 A T 0.0094
....
```

I want to remove a part of lines only in a column. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What you have tried so far ?

Comment: I tried to modify this, https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159751/keep-only-certain-part-of-a-string-in-a-certain-column but never suceeded...

Comment: I think we should combine something like as below
```
cut -d_ -f1,2 file
```
Or I think I should just make a file only by the command above, then combine two files from the $2-$5 from the first file.

Comment: How do you identify lines where you remove column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk '{split($1,Arr,"_");$1=Arr[1]"_"Arr[2]}1' test.txt
1_2345 0.123 A T 0.0094
4_9784 0.00034 C G 0.924
10_536 0.4456 AAAA TGGTT 0.00045
3_9874 0.55563 C T 0.8824
5_35555 0.123 A T 0.0094
```

Split the first column with _ (underscore) and replace the first column with only first two array values.

Comment: Kamaraj - Thank you so much again!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try also

```
awk '{sub ("_" $3 "_" $4, "", $1)} 1' file
```